# Angular 2+ deserialization with json2typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am using Json2Typescript to serialize and serialize typescript object. The problem is that I am not able to deserialize a JSON Data that I receive from my back-end.

This is my typescript class:

```
@JsonObject('Respondent')
export class Respondent {
    @JsonProperty('id',Number)
    Id:number;

    video:string;

    @JsonProperty('synchro_id',Number)
    SynchroId:string;

    @JsonProperty('language',String)
    Language:string;

    @JsonProperty('project_id',Number)
    ProjectId:number;

    @JsonProperty('terminal_id',Number)
    TerminalId:number;

    @JsonProperty('questionnaire_id',Number)
    QuestionnaireId: number;

    @JsonProperty('device_type_id',Number)
    DeviceTypeId:string;
    // TODO: This is to be removed
    medias: Media[] = null;
  // TODO: This is to be removed
    clicks: Click[] = null;

    @JsonProperty('email_status',String)
    emailStatus:string;

    @JsonProperty('inserted_local_time',String)
    insertedTime:string;

    @JsonProperty('responses',[Answer])
    Answers:Answer[];// TSMap<number,Answer>;  // {[key: number]: Answer[]} = {};

    @JsonProperty('size_on_disk',Number)
    sizeOnDisk:number;

    @JsonProperty('email_opened',Boolean)
    emailOpened:boolean;

    @JsonProperty('token',String)
    token:string;

    constructor() {

    }
...
}
```

This is how I deserialize my JSON.

```js
private getRespondents(start:number,end:number) {

        this._projectService.getRespondentsByRange(start,end,-1,-1,-1,this.questionnaire.id,-1,false).subscribe((respondents) => {
                this.respondents = new Array<Respondent>();

                this.respondents = new JsonConvert().deserializeArray(respondents,Respondent);  // doe s not work

                if(this.respondents!=null && this.respondents.length>0) {
                  this._sizeOnDisk = this.respondents[0].sizeOnDisk * this._nbOfRespondents;
                }
            },
            error => this._errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found the answer.

It is not explicitly specified in the official doc.

YOU HAVE TO INITIALIZE THE CLASS ATTRIBUTES.

```
@JsonProperty("email", String)
public email: String = "";
```

[Check this link for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951741/angular2-json2typescript-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-does-not-work)